# How to rewrite some part of code in order to bypass error: SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

Tags: javascript

I building by JavaScript source code using build tool.

This tools create an error

```
error: SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
```

When using `this._parts[part]` as in the example below.

I would like to know how to rewrite this code so error will disappear considering `this._parts` contains an array of strings populated dynamically .

```
var html = '';
Object.keys(this._parts).forEach(function (part, index) {
       html += this._parts[part].class; // error here
}, this);
```

Notes: I am using dojo build tools for processing the code and I am aware of using pragma excluding part of the code from build process, here I am interested in rewrite the code itself, thanks.

Comment: try `html += part.class;` or `html += this._parts[index].class;`

Comment: using html += this._parts[index].class; change sense of the code, I need use part and not index... thanks for posting anyway :)

Comment: Does every property of `this._parts` have a property called `class`? You can try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0xt91s79/). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bracket notation with apostrophes around `class` solves my issue.

`class` is a reserved keywords in JS and the building tool did not allow it.

```
var html = '';
Object.keys(this._parts).forEach(function (part, index) {
       html += this._parts[part]['class']; // now it is ok
}, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation

```
this['_parts'][part]
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the mistake